# Proof of curvature of vector and orthogonality of vector derivative to itself

Tags: calculus

In the proof of curvature of a vector r(t) we take the first derivative of r(t) to be orthogonal to the vector itself. But isn't it true only for r(t) with constant magnitude?

Comment: Yes. In general $r'(t)$ is not orthogonal to $r(t)$ itself. It happens if and only if the norm of $r(t)$ is constant.

Comment: Then how do we apply it to a curvature where r(t) changes?

Comment: The general expression for the curvature is $$\kappa(t)=\frac{\|r'(t)\times r''(t)\|}{\|r'(t)\|^3} .$$

Answer (score 0):

(At first, you don’t prove but define curvature instead.) Curvature deals with orthogonality, sort of: it may be defined as the normal component of the acceleration, divided by the square of the velocity.